# A question on binary polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

This is probably a well-known result but I was not able to find a reference on my search. My question concerns general polynomials $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $f$ cannot be written as a product of linear polynomials of the forms $a_1 x + a_2 y, b_1 x + b_2, c_1 + c_2y$ where $a_i, b_i, c_i \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ are complex numbers. In particular, if $f$ is homogeneous, then $f$ can be written as a product of linear forms.

So what is the density of binary polynomials over the integers that cannot be written as a product of linear polynomials over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: I believe it's true that almost all binary polynomials of any given degree are absolutely irreducible (hence in particular do not factor as the product of linear polynomials). But I couldn't immediately find a reference to a theorem that proves this.

Comment: I think Greg's claim follows by a consideration of the Newton polytopes. The probability that the newton polygon can be written as a Minkowski sum of smaller polygons should tend to zero as the degree gets large.

Comment: What is the definition of density? (and of binary polynomials? Google points "binary polynomial" to polynomials over a finite field of characteristic 2)

Comment: "Density" in this sense would be counting all polynomials of degree $d$ say where each coefficient has height at most $N$

Comment: @Stanley: this is not a definition... given a set $X$ of polynomials in $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}[x,y]$ you are defining a counting function $f_X(d,N)$ (say valued in $[0,1]$, if you normalize). Density means you assume that some limit exists, but which limit? Also, what do you call binary polynomial?